# Firebase Cloud Functions: how to update value that multiple functions use

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have multiple cloud functions that use a single value, basically something like this:

**index.js**

```
function emailFooter() {
    return `<div>email footer</div>`;
}

exports.sendEmailSuccess = functions.https.onCall(() => {
    const emailContent = 'success content' + emailFooter();
    sendEmail(emailContent) // fake email sender
});

exports.sendEmailFailure = functions.https.onCall(() => {
    const emailContent = 'failure content' + emailFooter();
    sendEmail(emailContent) // fake email sender
});
```

The problem is that I want to change the footer content (returned by `emailFooter`), but in order to do so (as far as I've researched) I first have to change it in the code and then deploy every single cloud function that uses `emailFooter` (`sendEmailSuccess` and `sendEmailFailure`), so the footer will look the same on each type of email.

Of course, I could just deploy all the functions at the same time with `firebase deploy --only functions`, but we used to be multiple developers and some of us updated functions to the point we don't know which ones are the same in **index.js** as in GCP (about 20 functions) and I'd have to check each one so I wouldn't deploy an old version.

Is there a way to update this single value or at least know which functions are up to date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If the single value can only be provided by code, then there is no way to update that value without also redeploying each function.  Code is not shared between function instances - each one has its own copy.

If you want to share a value between functions, and it can change over time, you will need to put that value somewhere else, for example, a database.  Each function can then query that other source for the value, even after it changes.